# My outer div background does not apply to my inner div

Tags: css

I have two divs nested inside of a div.  I set my background in the outer div but it only applied to the first inner div.  I can fix the problem by setting the height of the outer div but then I would have to change the height every time I modify the height of the inner div.  My code is below.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
</head>
<style>
 .redgradient{
    background: linear-gradient(#f75d5d,#ed7878   );
}
#intro{
    float: left;
    padding-left: 20px;
    width: 400px;
}
 </style>

<body>
 <div class="container ">
     <div class="redgradient">
          <div >
             <h1>Kendall Ponder's Wonderful Life</h1><p />
          </div>
          <div id="intro">
               Here is some text.
         </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the style is outside of the `<head>` tag?

Comment: for some reason removing the float:left; fixes it... i'm no css expert so I don't know why that's the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `overflow: hidden;` to wrapper `div`

```
.redgradient{
    background: linear-gradient(#f75d5d,#ed7878   );
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Check this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/amoljawale/79hUD/)

If you remove the `float` from `#intro` then also it works. No need to add 'overflow: hidden;'.

If you want to use floated elements, make sure to `clear` them properly.

Comment: why does this work? what caused the problem initially?

Comment: Its happened due to floated element used inside. `overflow:hidden;` makes it clear.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Would I be better off to avoid float?  The class I am taking used float to line elements up.  Would overflow:auto also work?  Thanks again!

Comment: `overflow:auto` also works but to `clear` the `floated` elements always use `clearfix` method. You can refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best]